# React Typescript: Ant Design Table with Dropdown Column pass Record to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

Following `Column`:

```
{ title: "Action", render: (record: ToDoClass) => { //<- this record
   return (
      <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
         <Button>
            User <DownOutlined />
         </Button>
      </Dropdown>
   )
}},
```

has the `menu`:

```
const menu = (
   <Menu onClick={updateUser}>
      <Menu.Item key="0" />
      <Menu.Item key="1">User 1</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">User 2</Menu.Item>
   </Menu>
);
```

must call the `function: updateUser` with the parameter `record` from the `columns` and `key` from the `menu`:

```
const updateUser = ({ key }: { key: React.Key }): void => { //<- need record here
   console.log(key);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/menu/), the `onClick` prop takes a function that takes an object `{ item, key, keyPath, domEvent }`. You can try changing your `_updateUser` and `menu` to something like this:

```js
<Menu onClick={this._updateUser}>
...
private _updateUser = ({ item, key }: { item: ToDoClass, key: any }): void => {
   console.log(item, key);
}
```

Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-panini-vt737?file=/src/Test.tsx) I created based on your code. Note the difference on how `onClick` is assigned. Also, since `item` is circular, it will crash the browser when it is printed.

Comment: TS2304 (TS) Cannot find name 'key'. Same on item

Comment: I made a mistake on the syntax. I updated the answer.

Comment: Still nothing, it feels like the function is not being called, because the console is empty. Like no ```Console.log()``` trigger has been called

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. Just to double check, you clicked the `Menu` right?

Comment: Yes. I clicked the Button from the Menu. I added an Screenshot

Comment: I see. Could you maybe create a minimum runnable example? I don't see obvious problems from the code you posted.

Comment: I created one above.

Comment: Okay but how can I use the ```record``` from the ```columns``` in this function? ```item``` is not ```record``` or?